# Not able to figure out where to check the length array

Tags: java, android

I know what is a Null Pointer exception, but my question is I'm not able to figure out how to handle it and give a toast message to user saying the list is null in the following code. I am creating an image gallery for my app and I am specifying the path from which the system should load all the files and folders into my Android application.

When there are no files or folders in the path, the app crashes saying:

```
Attempting to invoke length on a null array.
```

**GalleryFragment.java**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon);
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_perm_media_black_24dp);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.Gallery));
    TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitle);
    title.setText(getString(R.string.galleryLabel));
    toolbar.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tile_green));
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_green_24dp));

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    setGridAdapter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

    return view;
}
private void setGridAdapter(String path) {
    // Create a new grid adapter

gridItems = createGridItems(path);

MyGridAdapter adapter = new MyGridAdapter(getContext(), gridItems);

// Set the grid adapter
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Set the onClickListener
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (gridItems.get(position).isDirectory()) {
            setGridAdapter(gridItems.get(position).getPath());
        }
        else {
            gridItems.get(position).getImage();
        }
    }
});

gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (gridItems.get(position).isDirectory()) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
            dialog.setTitle("Test");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_recognition);
            dialog.show();
            return false;
        } else {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
            dialog.setTitle("Test");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);
            dialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
}

private List<GridViewItem> createGridItems(String directoryPath) {
    List<GridViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // List all the items within the folder.
    File[]  files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles(new ImageFileFilter());
        for (File file : files) {

            // Add the directories containing images or sub-directories
            if (file.isDirectory()
                    && file.listFiles(new ImageFileFilter()).length > 0) {

                items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), true, null));
            }
            // Add the images
            else {
                Bitmap image = BitmapHelper.decodeBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                        50,
                        50);
                items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), false, image));
            }
        }
    return items;
}



/**
 * Checks the file to see if it has a compatible extension.
 */
private boolean isImageFile(String filePath) {
    if (filePath.endsWith(".jpg") || filePath.endsWith(".png"))
    // Add other formats as desired
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * This can be used to filter files.
 */
private class ImageFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (isImageFile(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**GalleryAdapter.java**

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List < GridViewItem > items;
    private Context mContext;


    public MyGridAdapter(Context context, List < GridViewItem > items) {
        mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(items.get(position).getPath());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bitmap image = items.get(position).getImage();

        if (image != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        } else {
            // If no image is provided, display a folder icon.
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folder_grey_24dp);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I want to listFiles only if the length of the array is greater than zero. I don't know where to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enhanced `for` loop will fail if you try to iterate over a `null` array.  So one option here would be to just check for that possibility and iterate only if there is a non null array of files.

```
private List<GridViewItem> createGridItems(String directoryPath) {
    List<GridViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // List all the items within the folder.
    File[]  files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles(new ImageFileFilter());
    if (files != null) {  // check here for null
        for (File file : files) {
            // Add the directories containing images or sub-directories
            if (file.isDirectory()
                    && file.listFiles(new ImageFileFilter()).length > 0) {

                items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), true, null));
            }
            // Add the images
            else {
                Bitmap image = BitmapHelper.decodeBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                        50,
                        50);
                items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), false, image));
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Change is put null check before for loop like below**

```
private List<GridViewItem> createGridItems(String directoryPath) {
List<GridViewItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

// List all the items within the folder.
File[]  files = new File(directoryPath).listFiles(new ImageFileFilter());

       if(files != null && files.length != 0) {

       for (File file : files) {

        // Add the directories containing images or sub-directories
        if (file.isDirectory()
                && file.listFiles(new ImageFileFilter()).length > 0) {

            items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), true, null));
        }
        // Add the images
        else {
            Bitmap image = BitmapHelper.decodeBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    50,
                    50);
            items.add(new GridViewItem(file.getAbsolutePath(), false, image));
        }
    }
 }
return items;
}
```

**Next in getItemCount of MyGridAdapter write logic for empty list like below**

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {

     if(item.size == 0) {
        Log.d("List Size :", "List is empty");
        //If you want to toast message accepts context in your constructor
        //Then toast message 
     }

     return items.size();
}
```